# Doctrine 2: How to get last status from dedicated status table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, doctrine-orm

I have two tables: mail and status.

```
CREATE TABLE mail
(
  mail_id integer NOT NULL,
  mail_from character varying NOT NULL,
  mail_to character varying NOT NULL,
  subject character varying NOT NULL,
  text text,
  CONSTRAINT mail_pkey PRIMARY KEY (mail_id)
)

CREATE TABLE mail_status
(
  status_id integer NOT NULL,
  mail_id integer NOT NULL,
  code integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT mail_status_pkey PRIMARY KEY (status_id)
)
```

How to get with Doctrine 2 all mail rows with last status code where status code = 1.

E.g. SQL:

```
SELECT mail.*
FROM mail
WHERE (SELECT code FROM mail_status WHERE mail_status.mail_id = mail.mail_id ORDER BY mail_status.status_id DESC LIMIT 1) = 1
```

Comment: Do you need help creating the query. Or executing a query on php? If you need help with first will help if you provide a schema on SqlFiddle like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3

Comment: I need help executing query on php with Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

In MailBundle/Entity/Repository/MailRepository

```
public function findEmailsByStatusCode($code)
{ 
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('mail');
    $qb
        ->select('mail')
        ->from('Path\MailBundle\Entity\Mail', 'mail')
        ->join('mail.statuses', 'mailStatus')
        ->where('mailStatus.code = :code'))
        ->orderBy('mailStatus.creationDate', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy('mail.mail_id')
        ->setParameter('code', $code)
    ;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Then from the controller just call

```
$mailRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MailBundle:Mail');
$email = $mailRepository->findEmailsByStatusCode(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But this query fetch all statuses. mail_status table contains all the status history. And your query  fetch all mail statuses.

Comment: Sorry I got confused with the query that you wrote, check it again, It will bring all the emails that has last status true

Comment: I have error: "Error: 'ms' does not point to a ResultVariable".

Comment: Maybe need use "orderBy('ms.statusId', 'DESC')"?

Comment: try again, forgot to add the status attribute, can you write you MailStatus and Mail class?

Comment: Do you want to order it as well?

Comment: No, this select by any status, but I want to select by last status.

Comment: Do you have a field called creationDate in MailStatus? If you do, check if it's working like this.

Comment: Yes, I have field creationDate. To simplify I removed this field.